# SQL SUM enquiry

Tags: sql

So I'm new to SQL/self taught and I have built the below code, (i know its ugly but its a combination of google/stack over flow/me mucking through it, I need to SUM the "inforce, submitted,  and deferred, under assessment defined in the #step4 in separate column, i have been running in circles all day, so if anyone can answer that would be cool. I'M getting NULL  from the SUM line other steps work fine.

```
SELECT DISTINCT #step1.staff_user_id,
                #step1.PBUID,
                #step1.staff_Branch,
                #step1.create_time,
                #step2.UserFullName,
                #step2.PositionName,
                Isnull(#step2.KBDepartmentName, 'Franchise') kb2,
                #step2.USERID                                AS userid2,
                #step2.EmployeeStatus,
                #step2.dss_current_flag,
                #step3.KBDivisionName,
                Sum(#step4.Inforce)                          AS Inforce,
                Sum(#step4.Submitted)                        AS Submitted,
                Sum(#step4.deferred)                         AS Deferred,
                Sum(#step4.[Under Assessment])               AS UnderAssessment
FROM   #step1
       LEFT JOIN #STEP2
              ON #step1.staff_user_id = #step2.UserId
       LEFT JOIN #STEP3
              ON #step1.staff_user_id = #step3.UserId
       LEFT JOIN #step4
              ON #step1.staff_user_id = #step4.Staff_user_Name
WHERE  #step2.dss_current_flag = 'Y'
       AND #step2.employeestatus = 'Active'
GROUP  BY #step1.staff_user_id,
          #step1.PBUID,
          #step1.staff_Branch,
          #step1.create_time,
          #step2.UserFullName,
          #step2.PositionName,
          Isnull(#step2.KBDepartmentName, 'Franchise'),
          #step2.USERID,
          #step2.EmployeeStatus,
          #step2.dss_current_flag,
          #step3.KBDivisionName
```

Comment: which database are you using ?

Comment: Without looking at the original data it is hard to tell, but try moving the `where` filters to `on` condition like this `..LEFT JOIN #STEP2
on #step1.staff_user_id=#step2.UserId and #step2.dss_current_flag = 'Y' and #step2.employeestatus='Active'..`

Comment: `#step1.staff_user_id=#step4.Staff_user_Name` looks suspicious - would `#step4.UserId` be correct?

Comment: what data types are those columns you are calling Sum() on?

Comment: To further @AnthonyMcGrath 's point, would `COUNT` be correct, as the field names sound like flags rather than values.

Comment: Thanks everyone Ken's observation was correct what a fantastic community,  I feel slightly silly now.

Comment: @Nate keep in mind that `#step1
       LEFT JOIN #STEP2` will work as `#step1
       INNER JOIN #STEP2` since `step2` filters are present in `Where` clause

Comment: This is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` when `GROUP BY`... How come?